# How to fix: 'can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC' using Cmake. Using plain g++ works

Tags: c++, cmake, boost-python

I get a message 'can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC'

I have try other examples and the issue is the same.

I have try

- changing from MODULE to SHARED
- cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC
- and other variations

**this works:**

```
c++ -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m ../account.cpp

c++ -shared -Wall -Werror -Wl,--export-dynamic account.o -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_python36 -o account.so
```

**Here is the basic cmake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Test)

find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)

find_package(PythonLibs ${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR} EXACT REQUIRED)

find_package(Boost 1.70.0 COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

add_library(account SHARED account.cpp)

target_link_libraries(account Boost::python)

target_include_directories(account PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set_target_properties(account PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Using: make VERBOSE=1 the output commands are:

```
c++  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -Daccount_EXPORTS -I/usr/include/python3.6m -isystem /usr/local/include  -fPIC   -o CMakeFiles/account.dir/account.cpp.o -c /src/boost_python_example/account.cpp

c++ -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,account.so -o account.so CMakeFiles/account.dir/account.cpp.o /usr/local/lib/libboost_python36.a
```

So the cmake is not getting the same paths and flags, I am learning cmake so Im trying to understand this problem. Clearly the problem is not on actual libs but telling cmake where to find the proper ones.

Comment: From a clean slate, try to make a verbose build (`make VERBOSE=1`) to see what commands (and options/flags) are actually used to build the library. Is CMake doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Please, add **exact error message** to the question post, with exact filenames. In the current form the error description is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quite simple. Comparing both commands what was missing on the cmake command was: *--export-dynamic*

So I solved using **option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build libraries as shared as opposed to static" ON)** interesting enough the comment is needed.

**Working solution:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Test)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build libraries as shared as opposed to static" ON)
find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs ${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR} EXACT REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.70.0 COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
add_library(account SHARED account.cpp)
target_link_libraries(account Boost::python)
target_include_directories(account PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set_target_properties(account PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

Thanks everyone for the comments they lead me to a solution